# How to train a model in tensorflow using java

Tags: java, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to find a tutorial which can help in train a image classification model in java. I should work same way we train model in python.

Answer (score 5):

Current version of Tensorflow (1.3) java API does not allow to train models, but allow to use pre-trained models only.

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I agree with you. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: That's correct. Currently you can deploy in Java models you have trained in Python, but I don't think you can train models from Java yet. In particular, some of the Python libraries (e.g., the gradient computation) are needed for training. Longer term we'd like to support training everywhere, but it's a lot of work. Contributions welcome!

Comment: Right now I didn't find any resource to train a image classifier in java using tensorflow. I managed to do that using another library deeplearning4j. I will use python to train image classifier in tensorflow and call the model from java.

Comment: @PeterHawkins, The model that is created using tensorflow, is it supported in other libraries like keras and deeplearing4j. I saw deeplearing4j supports keras. Just curious if tensorflow model can be called from other libraries.

Comment: @PeterHawkins Am I clear understand: there are no plans in Google to develop java version of tensorflow with train feature?

Comment: @AlexanderFedyukov, are there any news about this topic? It seems that I cannot find any at least.

Comment: @Elydasian, unfortunately, we haven't no good news. Tensorflow grows in javascript way and in others, but are ignoring sweet java. That is the why I'm  take a look  aparapi project.

Comment: @AlexanderFedyukov, fail, but, thx for the reply, I'll take a look at the Aparapi Project

Comment: @Elydasian Oh, really? I've not a long experience with aparapi and was wonder how easy to make parallel calcs from java and got 10x improvments of calcs on my modest video card with it. But I agree with you: future of this project is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

For that, we can use the JavaCPP Presets for TensorFlow, which map the C and C++ APIs:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tensorflow

Comment: this seems like the a great solution.. i will give a look. thanks