# model optimizer tensorflow in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm trying to make a TensorFlow model in Java without using Python.
I managed to do a lot of the Python code to Java, but I'm missing some elements to finalize.
I'm blocking on the optimizer.
The original code in Python is a very simple model.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Batch of input and target output (1x1 matrices)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name='input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name='target')

# Trivial linear model
y_ = tf.identity(tf.layers.dense(x, 1), name='output')

# Optimize loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y), name='loss')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

I started the transformation into Java, I'm not far from the end but I'm stuck on the optimizer.

```
try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
   //# Batch of input and target output (1x1 matrices)
   //x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name='input')
   Output<OperationBuilder> x = g.opBuilder("Placeholder", "input")
                .setAttr("dtype", DataType.FLOAT)
                .build().output(0);
   //y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name=target')
   Output<OperationBuilder> y = g.opBuilder("Placeholder", "target")
                .setAttr("dtype", DataType.FLOAT)
                .build().output(0);
   //# Trivial linear model
   //y_ = tf.identity(tf.layers.dense(x, 1), name='output')
   Tensor t = Tensor.create(new int[] {0});
   Output reductionIndices = g.opBuilder("Const", "layer")
                .setAttr("dtype", t.dataType()).setAttr("value", t)
                .build().output(0);
   Output dense = g.opBuilder("layersdense", "dense")
                .setAttr("T", DataType.FLOAT)
                .setAttr("Tidx", DataType.INT32)
                .addInput(input).addInput(reductionIndices)
                .build().output(0);

   Tensor<?> t2 = Tensor.create(dense);
   Output<OperationBuilder> y_ = g.opBuilder("Identity", "output")
                .setAttr("value", t2)
                .build().output(0);
   //# Optimize loss
   //loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y), name='loss')
   Output<OperationBuilder> sub=g.opBuilder("Sub","sub")
        .addInput(y_).addInput(y)
        .build().output(0);
   Output<OperationBuilder> sq = g.opBuilder("Square", "Square")
        .addInput(sub)
        .build().output(0);
   //optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
   Code java ???
   //train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')
   Code java ???

}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030577/how-to-train-a-model-in-tensorflow-using-java . The last time I checked, the Java api allowed only to load a trained model and make predictions, so that you can easily use a neural net trained with Python in your Android-Java-App. "Some elements" that you are missing seems to be <em>the entire optimization framework</em>. Since Tensor-Flow relies heavily on heavily optimized low-level code written in C/C++, porting the entire thing to Java does not seem easy or even desirable.

Comment: Andrey is correct in that the optimizer libraries are not available in Java. However, those libraries are essentially adding to the TensorFlow graph, so you could replicate them in Java (without having to port any of the C/C++ code). However, in general, if possible, you're probably better off creating the model in Python and then executing the training loop from Java. For example see: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/training

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I thought all computational functions were in the tensorflow_jni.dll and called with JNI. It's possible to call "Placeholder, Const, Sub, Square ...", I thought that all the functions that we call PYTHON were also JAVA.

Comment: Many of the Python functions are composite ones that encapsulate multiple operations in the graph. For example, the `tf.layers.dense` function adds the matrix multiplication, bias addition and activation function - so adds multiple nodes to the graph. These high level conveniences are not yet implemented in other languages, so you have to add each operation individually.  Long story short, as of January 2018, my recommendation would be to create and export the model from a Python program, even if you drive the training process from Java.

Comment: OK, thanks.
I will install PYTHON and use it to generate the graph.

Comment: Thank you, I did not find how to close the question.

Comment: @ash, Hi, are there any new information on this topic? I can't find any on the internet... :(

Answer (score 0):

I also faced much troubles during some post processing on an inferred output. A solution I can suggest is to import the entire graph .pb file (Including the necessary nodes of the optimizer and loss function), which is defined using python and run the s.runner inside 2 "for" loop which feeds your batches and perform epochs. Note that I haven't tried this method, but  in my experience, avoiding the java specific graph builder would help you significantly.
Best of luck